# How to Increment 1 day in Date using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a scenario in which we need to increment 1 day in existing date. Like In `<subscriptionDate>2015-05-06</subscriptionDate>` I want to increase 1 day and map its value to  `<terminationDate>2015-05-07</terminationDate>`. How can I achieve this using XSLT. So, all date constraints should also be handled. like if day is 31 then increment in month.

```
<Subscription code="12345678R1">
      <userAccount>40000005b</userAccount>
      <offerTemplate>Test</offerTemplate>
      <subscriptionDate>2015-05-06</subscriptionDate>
      <terminationDate></terminationDate>
</Subscription>
```

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, not both. Makes a huge difference in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 you can add a duration to an date e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="terminationDate">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(preceding-sibling::subscriptionDate) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTP.

Comment: @Martin, How can we increment the date if the format is of as following: 2015-05-03T00:00:00Z

Comment: @omerkhalid, that is a `xs:dateTime` so you can use `xs:dateTime(' 2015-05-03T00:00:00Z') + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')` to get a new `xs:dateTime` to which the duration was added.

Answer (score 1):

I can add that I was banging away for awhile before I realized the xs: namespace was missing. I usually only use the xsl: functions.

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" **xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"** version="2.0">

If it isn't declared the xs:date function and xs:dayTimeDuration won't work.

Also this is a resource from ibm on the types

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=system-date-time-data-types